# The Proof that a Function is Non-Constant

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, polynomials

Recently I was faced with the following. Let $P_1(x), P_2(x)$ and $P_3(x)$ be non-constant polynomials with integer coefficients and let $\Omega=\{z\in \mathbb{C} : P_1(z)P_2(z)P_3(z)\neq 0\}$.

Define the function $\psi:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$
\psi(z) =  P_2(z)^{P_3(z)}\log P_1(z),
$$
where the we may choose the main value (branch) of the complex logarithm.

I would like to prove that this function is non-constant. However, I did not find a proof for that. I tried to use the standard approaches (by derivating etc) without success.

Any help is very welcomed.

Comment: Hint: let $x \in \Omega \cap \mathbb R^+$ and show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} |\Psi(x)|$ is either $\,0\,$ or $\,+\infty\,$, so $|\Psi(x)|$ cannot be constant.